# Is there such a thing as a vice on a stand?

Tags: tools, shed

I have a small shed with a concrete foundation. I need a vice in the shed, but there's no room for a big, heavy workbench to keep it in place. I can't bolt it to the wall of the shed, because it's flimsy wood and will not withstand the force I'll need to apply to stuff.

So, what I want is a vice atop to a solid metal post, about 3 foot high, with big, strong bolts so I can drill into the foundation and secure it. Do I have to make this myself or does it exist to be bought?

Comment: If you want it on your wall, you could attach a piece of wood across two studs.

Comment: You want a metal vice?  There are freestanding woodworking vices [like this](http://www.rockler.com/superjaws-sja200-portable-clamping-system)...

Answer (score 2):

There are stands that can be purchased off the shelf. A heavy duty grinder stand would work those are easy to find online an come in different strengths , I used some square tube steel for my large vice , purchased from a metal scrap yard at a big savings compared to purchasing a premade one or new steel cut to length.

Comment: +1, any industrial tool supply place will have them, some as low as like $100.

Comment: Yep. Square tubing and appropriate angle iron, all bolted together nice and neat, would do just fine. I've managed to avoid learning to weld for 30 years by doing such things.